# Flutter - GlobalKey Dulicate error even when I remove the GlobalKey from the code

Tags: flutter, events, runtime-error, global-key

The title may not tell the whole story. I have been trying to locate an error in my flutter calendar events application - using SFCalendar - but I am unable to figure out what exactly is the problem. Kindly help!

Use the link below to find the github rep with an MRE:

[This is the link to the Github repository where an Minimal Reproducible Example is created!](https://github.com/GodRishUniverse/MyCalendarWidget)

Comment: try use UniqKey()

Comment: but @SachinKumawat if I use UniqueKey then I cannot use it for validation of textFormfields and I cannot get its currentState